# Running qt creator via remote desktop

Tags: c++, linux, qt, arm, remote-access

We are developing a software using QT creator. The software is meant to run on windows and on an ARM mini-computer running Debian. To test the software on the mini-computer, we logged in on the mini computer using ssh and an exported display. Some programs like Inkscape run fine, but we can't get to run QT Creator. It always displays the following errors:

```
No tool chain set from kit "Desktop".
No tool chain set from kit "Desktop".
Cant find EGLConfig, returning null config
Unable to find an X11 visual which matches EGL config 0
Could not initialize OpenGL for RasterGLSurface, reverting to RasterSurface.
Cant find EGLConfig, returning null config
Unable to find an X11 visual which matches EGL config 0
Could not initialize OpenGL
```

We also tried to log in from another x86 linux computer, but this created the same errors. Thus we suppose that the problems are linked to the architecture. Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

EDIT: We just tried to access QT creator from another ARM Debian mini-computer and it also fails. Thus it does not seem to be related to the architecture as we first suspected.

(We could of course do cross compiling and remote debugging, but we try to avoid this)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try loading qtcreator without the Welcome addon:

```
qtcreator -noload Welcome
```

The Welcome addon uses OpenGL which probably isn't supported by X forwarding.

Comment: That was easy. It works. Thanks. Is the Welcome addon really only the small screen you get when you start QT Creator?

Comment: It gives you a nice "Getting started", "Recent projects" and "Recent sessions" view. But why they needed to use OpenGL for that, I don't know. It has caused me only pain after they introduced this. Now, I always disable this plugin on my QtCreator installations.

Comment: I like this screen on windows but I can surely live without it for the remote sessions that use X forwarding.

Comment: FWIW, this isn't enough anymore. With v4.2.0 you had to exclude the `AnalyzerBase` plugin as well. That plugin has gone in the 4.4 beta, and the application no longer loads even with `-noload all`.